# Filter a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to filter a dataframe for a certain date in a column.
The colum entries are timestamps and I try to construct a boolean vector from those,
checking for a certain date.
I tried:

```
filterfr = df[((df.expiration.month==6) & (df.expiration.day==22) & (df.expiration.year==2002)]
```

It doesn't work, because 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

When you do `df.expiration`, you get back a `Series` where the items are the expiration datetimes.

Try comparing to an actual `datetime.datetime` object:

```
filterfr = df[df['expiration'] == datetime.datetime(2002, 6, 22)]
```

You may want to look into using a [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), depending on your dataset. This lets you use the convenient syntax

```
df['2002-06-22']
```

Comment: This will only work if at the start of the day (it won't for other timestamps±)

Answer (score 3):

To have access to the DatetimeIndex methods you have to wrap it in DatetimeIndex (currently*).

The fastest way is to access the day, month and year attributes (just like you attempted):

```
expir = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['expiration'])
(expir.day == 22) & (expir.month == 6) & (expir.year == 2002)
```

Alternative, but *slower* ways are to use the normalize method (to bring it to the start of the day), or to use the date attribute:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['expiration']).normalize() == datetime.datetime(2002, 06, 22)

pd.DatetimeIndex(df['expiration']).date == datetime.datetime(2002, 06, 22)
```

---

*In 0.15 there will be a dt attribute so that you can access these as:

```
expir = df['expiration']
expir.dt.day ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This
filterfr = df[df['expiration'] == datetime.datetime(2002, 6, 22)]
worked fine.

However, after doing some filtering, I got an error,
when trying to do filterfr.expiration[0]
or filterfr['expiration'][0]
to get the first element in the series.
KeyError: 0L  is raised, although there are elements in the series.
The series looks like this:
Name: expiration, Length: 534668, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Shouldn't this actually always work?